# What kinds of commands can be run by xargs?

Tags: xargs

From findutils' manual:

```
xargs [option...] [command [initial-arguments]]
```

Am I correct that `xargs` runs `command` in several run, each of which with different sequence of arguments?

If yes, does it mean that such a command must satisfy that 
applying a sequence of arguments to the command is **effectively the same as**

- splitting the sequence of arguments into subsequences, and
- running the command with each subsequence of arguments in a different run?

For example, is it correct that if `mycommand` can be run by `xargs`, then

```
mycommand arg1 arg2 arg3
```

must be effectively the same as

```
mycommand arg1
mycommand arg2 arg3
```

Is the above condition a necessary and sufficient condition for a command to be executed by `xargs`?

Is there any command which doesn't satisfy the above condition? (I can't find any.) If there is, can it be run by `xargs`?

Can the arguments passed by `xargs` to `command` be any kind of arguments: options, option arguments, or nonoption arguments? I think this question is helpful for answering the above questions.

What if `-i` of `xargs` is involved?

Thanks.

Comment: You can't run a command with `xargs` that changes its semantics depending on the number of arguments, such as `mv` (with more than two arguments, the last argument needs to be a directory).

Comment: ... GNU `mv` solves this by its `-t` option: `... | xargs mv -t destdir`

Comment: If `arg2` begins with a hyphen, you may get different results in the second case if it's mistaken for an option. In general, if any of the added args  start with `-`, you may encounter errors. It's common for the author of a script that uses xargs to make sure there's a `--` at the end of initial-arguments if appropriate.

Comment: In addition to the issues with argument and/or option handling you seem to intend, `xargs` only runs a command that is actually a _program_, sometimes called an _external_ command. It cannot handle a shell alias or function, or a list or a compound command like `case` or a special builtin like `break exec eval`. In contrast `parallel` builds commands that are run by (child) shells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I correct that xargs runs command in several run, each of which with different sequence of arguments?

Yeah (unless the input to `xargs` repeats, of course)

> ```
> mycommand arg1 arg2 arg3
> ```
>
> must be effectively the same as
>
> ```
> mycommand arg1
> mycommand arg2 arg3
> ```

Pretty much, since in general, we can't know where `xargs` will split the list. GNU xargs has `--show-limits` which could be used to determine if all input fits in one run of the command.

Of course if the arguments must be passed to the command in sets of *N*, we can use `-n N` to have some control over it (or `-n M` with *M* some multiple of *N*).

> Is there any command which doesn't satisfy the above condition? (I can't find any.) If there is, can it be run by xargs?

Kusalananda mentioned `mv`, which has the issue that the last argument is treated differently from the others. In effect, the arguments added by `xargs` would need to go to the middle, and there's no standard way to do that. (FreeBSD xargs has `-J {}` that does it and GNU `mv` has the `-t dir` option to pass the target directory at the start of the argument list. `cp` is similar.)

Then something like `tar -czf foo.tar.gz` wouldn't work since `-c` (create) overwrites the archive on each run. That could be avoided by using `-r` (append) instead of `-c`, but at least GNU tar doesn't support appending to a compressed archive.

Luckily, most utilities work file-by-file and are designed to accept a list of files at the end.

> Can the arguments passed by xargs to command be any kind of arguments: options, option arguments, or nonoption arguments?

They're just strings, `xargs` doesn't know what they mean. If you had a utility that didn't accept the usual list of files, but took a `-f filename` option, you could arrange for `xargs` to get input like `-f file1 -f file2 ...` and it would happily pass that along. Though with lots of input, the size limit could again cause a split between a `-f` and a filename, but adding something like `-n 100` would make that unlikely (depending on the lengths of the filenames and the actual size limit).

> What if -i of xargs is involved?

`-i` in GNU xargs is the same as `-I {}`, and somewhat boringly makes `xargs` run the command once for each input argument. Helps if you need to put the argument to the middle of the command, but doesn't really help in reducing the number of invocations to the command.

Comment: Regarding that last bit, if used with `-P n` (if that nonstandard option is implemented to run the command in parallel), it may still be useful.

Answer (score 1):

The `xargs` tool reads (by default) space-delimited tokens from standard input and turns them into command-line options to the specified program.  By default, it will take as many tokens as can fit on a command line and run the command once with those tokens:

```
echo 1 2 3 | xargs echo "-"
- 1 2 3
```

Here, `xargs` read 1, 2, and 3, and runs `echo "-" 1 2 3`.  I'm including the `"-"` to help make it clear how many times `echo` is getting invoked.

You can limit the number of arguments that it will pass to the command using the `-n` option:

```
echo 1 2 3 | xargs -n2 echo "-"
- 1 2
- 3
```

Here, `xargs` read 2 tokens (the max) from its standard input stream, and run the command with those tokens as command-line parameters: `echo "-" 1 2`.  Since it wasn't yet finished reading the tokens from standard input, it continued by reading 3, encountered EOF, and ran the command again with the remaining parameters: `echo "-" 3`.

Adjusting the value of `n` will give you different behavior:

```
echo 1 2 3 | xargs -n1 echo "-"
- 1
- 2
- 3
```

*Edit:* Tim commented that I didn't answer his questions.  I disagree, and will try to explicitly call out the answers below:

> Am I correct that `xargs` runs `command` in several run, each of which with different sequence of arguments?

I addressed this question.  It can run command in one or several runs. By default, it try to run `command` as few times as possible (limited by argument length).

> If yes, does it mean that such a command must satisfy that applying a sequence of arguments to the command is effectively the same as (x) splitting the sequence of arguments into subsequences, and (x) running the command with each subsequence of arguments in a different run?

I addressed this question.  If the tokens are too long (or are limited by the `-n` option, then `xargs` splits them into subsequences and runs the command with the subsequences.  I even give examples of that happening.

> Is the above condition a necessary and sufficient condition for a command to be executed by `xargs`?

While I don't have an explicit answer to this, my thought was that the semantics could be inferred from the examples.  If the arguments to `command` have special meaning based on position, then `command` is likely not to be a good candicate for `xargs` (although I'm sure you could carefully craft cases that would work).

> Is there any command which doesn't satisfy the above condition? (I can't find any.) If there is, can it be run by xargs?

Again, you can carefully craft such a case (but I wouldn't recommend it).  A carefully crafted example is (running `mv a.txt b.txt`):

```
$ ls
a.txt
$ echo a.txt b.txt | xargs mv
$ ls
b.txt
```

> Can the arguments passed by xargs to command be any kind of arguments: options, option arguments, or nonoption arguments? I think this question is helpful for answering the above questions.

They are read a space-delimited tokens. They are passed to command as space-delimited arguments.  This will run `ls -l`:

```
$ echo -l | xargs ls
total 0
-rw-r----- 1 user group 0 Jun 7 15:16 b.txt
```

> What if `-i` of `xargs` is involved?

Ok, I didn't answer this one, but I don't really understand what you're asking in this context.